# How to change url of image which is generated dynamically just by using CSS and media queries?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I apologize in advance if I am asking asking question with impossible answer. But I just thought it was worth asking, maybe somebody knows how to achieve what I am asking for.

I have image on the page like this ( **image url is generated dynamically on the server by PHP** ):

```
<img src="/images_BIG/image_12345.jpg" />
```

Now - I would love to use only CSS media queries to change this image URL, let's say to this ( when browser viewport width is smaller than e.g. 800px ):

```
<img src="/images_SMALL/image_12345.jpg" />
```

I know this can be done by PHP (detecting mobile browsers and return appropriate URL) or use Javascript to change URL on the fly. But is this possible with CSS3 ? I am aiming only on HTML5 browsers so no need to care about IE.

Thank you for any thoughts and help in advance.

Comment: Why is JavaScript not a solution?

Comment: @Blowski It could be, however it would slow down rendering page considerably - especially when on mobile connection (waiting for page to fire document.ready() and then downloading missing images)

Comment: Check out this cool video: http://ontwik.com/html5-2/html5-and-css3-media-queries/. But as I have read your comment below, it does not show what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the image in a div. Use mobile first, so that it only downloads the small version of the image on small screens. On bigger screens, the image will be hidden and a background image will be there instead.

The two downsides - a non-semantic wrapping div, and the need to specify the height and width of the div. The upside is that you get the foreground image in the HTML.

The HTML

```
<div class="imgContainer"><img src="/images_SMALL/image_12345.jpg" /></div>
```

The CSS

```
// for screens bigger than 800px
@media screen and (min-device-width:800px) {
  div.imgContainer {
    background-image:url(../images_BIG/image_12345.jpg);
    background-size:100px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
  }
  img {
    display:none;
  }
}
```

---

EDIT
Based on your comment above, I would say add the wrapping div and set its background image with jQuery.

Comment: That could work, however please read my comments above - I can't use image url in CSS stylesheet, because it is generated dynamically on server.

Comment: @Frodik Code for mobile first - small images, CSS and JavaScript. Then override it on the PC. It depends on your exact use case - if there are lots (perhaps more than 100) medium sized-images, this would be slower. However, if it's just a few medium-to-large sized images, this will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a different css file depending on your media queries:

```
#image1 { background: url('/images_BIG/image_12345.jpg'); width: 600px; height: 200px; }
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
 #image1 { background: url('/images_SMALL/image_12345.jpg'); width: 300px; height: 100px; }
}
```

In this case, you would move away from an IMG tag to a different tag (`<span id="image1"></span>`).

Comment: I know this, but as I stated in my question - the image URL is generated dynamicly on the server, so I can't use its URL in CSS stylesheet because I actually don't know it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as I have read your comment...if the only problem is including variable urls into a css stylesheet...what about just php including (rendering) the stylesheet (wrapped with `<style>` tag) into the resulting html? Then you could use `<?php echo $imageUrl ?>` at the place of the url. I have never done this before, it might be a silly idea but it just appears possible to me now.